# Is the cryptanalysis domain part of the Data Science?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

The cryptanalysis is a domain for analysis the encryption algorithm and sometimes the way to break them using statistics, math and number theories.

My question is:

"are questions regarding specifically the cryptanalysis suitable for this site?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say "no", as there is an entire StackExchange site for Cryptography, and is definitely a more suitable place:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/